# How to center align logo on WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How can I center align the logo on this header? Also wanted to know how to enable background transparency for header background color and change the value for maximum size for the logo. Here is the CSS entry for the header section.

```
 #header {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 600;
  /* Higher than the sidebar widget and widget container, sliders */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #2F2E3C; }
  #header > .inner {
    position: relative; }
    #header > .inner > .wrap {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 76px; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #header > .inner > .warp {
      min-height: 80px; } }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #header > .inner {
      text-align: center; }
      #header > .inner > .wrap {
        min-height: 40px; } }

#header.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #header.sticky {
      position: static !important; } }
  #header.sticky .wrap {
    min-height: 0; }
  .boxed #header.sticky {
    max-width: 1180px;
    width: 96%; }
  .admin-bar #header.sticky {
    top: 32px; }
  #header.sticky #site-logo {
    top: 10px; }
  #header.sticky .dropdown-menu-wrap > ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu {
    top: 60px; }
  #header.sticky #primary-menu > ul.menu > li > a {
    line-height: 60px; }
  #header.sticky #top-header-area {
    display: none; }

#site-logo {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  top: 30px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0; }
  #site-logo a {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #494D4E;
    line-height: 36px;
    direction: ltr;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    /* Do not let logo get bigger than the header */
    font-family: "Lato", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      #site-logo a {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center; } }
    #site-logo a img {
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #site-logo {
      display: block;
      float: none;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
      top: 0;
      padding: 10px 0; }
      #site-logo a img {
        max-width: 75%;
        margin: 0 auto; } }

#site-description {
  margin: 0; }

#container {
  background: #f7f7f7;
```

Edit:

```
#header {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 600;
  /* Higher than the sidebar widget and widget container, sliders */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #2F2E3C; }
  #header > .inner {
    position: relative; }
    #header > .inner > .wrap {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 76px; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #header > .inner > .warp {
      min-height: 80px; } }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #header > .inner {
      text-align: center; }
      #header > .inner > .wrap {
        min-height: 40px; } }

#header.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #header.sticky {
      position: static !important; } }
  #header.sticky .wrap {
    min-height: 0; }
  .boxed #header.sticky {
    max-width: 1180px;
    width: 96%; }
  .admin-bar #header.sticky {
    top: 32px; }
  #header.sticky #site-logo {
    top: 10px; }
  #header.sticky .dropdown-menu-wrap > ul.menu > li > ul.sub-menu {
    top: 60px; }
  #header.sticky #primary-menu > ul.menu > li > a {
    line-height: 60px; }
  #header.sticky #top-header-area {
    display: none; }

#site-logo {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  top: 30px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0; }
  #site-logo a {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #494D4E;
    line-height: 36px;
    direction: ltr;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    /* Do not let logo get bigger than the header */
    font-family: "Lato", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      #site-logo a {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center; } }
    #site-logo a img {
      margin:auto;
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #site-logo {
      display: block;
      float: none;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
      top: 0;
      padding: 10px 0; }
      #site-logo a img {
        max-width: 75%;
        margin: 0 auto; } }

#site-description {
  margin: 0; }

#container {
  background: #f7f7f7; }
```

Comment: Pramathesh, Post the HTML code as well

Comment: Hi! I'm a little new to this. Can you tell me where would I find this, please

Comment: `Header.php` but a link to your result will be good.

Comment: Try `#site-logo a { text-align: center; }`. Currently it's set to `left`.

Comment: Here's the link to the website. www.happyvalleyschool.tk

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: inline-block;` from `#site-logo` then add `margin:auto;` to `#site-logo a img`.

**Edit:** I also noticed you have `float:center;` in `#site-logo` which is not a valid property, so I would consider removing it as it is redundant.

Comment: Not worki
site-logo {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  top: 30px;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0; }
  #site-logo a {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #494D4E;
    line-height: 36px;
    direction: ltr;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    /* Do not let logo get bigger than the header */
    font-family: "Lato", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      #site-logo a {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center; } }
    #site-logo a img {
      margin:auto;
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%; }

Comment: Sorry, could you edit that code out and edit it into in your question, please? It's hard to read there. Also, could you please be more precise? What's not working about it? Did anything change?

Comment: Hi! Just put the new code after edit in the question. Do let me know if I got it correct. I'm trying to get the main logo to move to the center. Change transparency for header background color and change the maximum value for logo size in the header.